# X11 Forwarding over ssh - Could not find ':' in DISPLAY: needs-to-be-defined

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, x11-forwarding

my computer is **windows 10**, I installed a **ubuntu 18.04** by **virtualbox**.

I want to run a **python program** in ubuntu from my windows and with **graphical output**.

However after running the program, it always reported:

```
Could not find ':' in DISPLAY: needs-to-be-defined  
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(Original:2079): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:39:33.441: cannot open display: 127.0.0.1:10.0
```

What I have done:

1: I did the setting in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` turned on:

```
ForwardX11 yes
ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

2: login with: `ssh username@pc-name -X`

3: changed the ip address:

```
$ export DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:10.0 # original was localhost:10.0
```

Do you know, what's wrong? Why I can not see the picture?

Comment: What X server are you running on Windows?  The Ubuntu side seems OK.

Comment: @ubfan1 Hi, I don't know which X server, Do you know, how to check which X server on windows???

Comment: Windows does not come with an X server so you have to install one.  There are free ones like vcxsrv you can get.  Haven't used it myself.

Comment: Hi ubfan1, just installed the vcxsrv, it works very well!!! Thanks very much for the help!!! *^^*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ubuntu side looks OK, but you need an X server on the Windows side.  Windows does not come with an X server so you have to install one. There are free ones like vcxsrv you can get. Haven't used it myself.